How to change hard disk bus type NVMe to SCSI in VMWare Fusion?
I use Rocky Linux and have to change my hard disk bus type but then my booting failed. However, it runs normally when i select the bus type NVMe.

Boot failed

How do i solve this? Should i make a new VM and choose SCSI from the start?

Why do you think you need (or want) SCSI?

IMHO, reattach VMDK to VM can help.

Switch to a "fallback" initramfs (e.g. on the bootloader menu, assuming one is generated on your system) that includes drivers for all potential bus/device type (instead of just driver for the one detected to be what the root filesystem "runs over").
